# Combine multiple strategies to generate a unique column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique, uniqueidentifier

I have an employee table with last_name and first_name columns. I want to generate a column called employee_code which will contain always 3 characters and will be unique. If it does not already exists, the code will be the first letter of first_name followed by two first letters of last name.

```
SELECT 'LUDOVIC' AS first_name, 'AUBERT' AS last_name, 'LAU' AS employee_code;
```

But if 'LAU' is already present, I want to use an alternate strategy, such as using the two first letters of first name followed by first letter of last name.

```
SELECT 'LUDOVIC' AS first_name, 'AUBERT' AS last_name, 'LUA' AS employee_code;
```

How can you achieve this in SQL?

Comment: What if both ```LAU``` and  ```LUA``` already present?

Comment: Then you would have to usher in a third strategy.

Comment: My recommendation would be using an Alphanumeric like ```LA0001``` instead of just letters, because there are lot of chances you may get same first and last name. then you need to keep changing your strategy.

Comment: I am dealing with a small database with a few hundred lines. My customer wants codes that possibly look like 'LAU' or 'LUA'. Something meaningfull for everyday use.

Comment: @Dale K, unfortunately, I am clueless.

Comment: *"Then you would have to usher in a third strategy."* We wouldn't need to; you need to define what that solution is. Unfortunately any such strategy, however, is likely going to need a recursive solution, which is going to get steadily slower the more employees you have. *Yes*, when a 3 character alpha value you could have up to 17,576 variations (from `'AAA'` to `'ZZZ'`) but you're very likely to get conflicts early on.

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . If you want a three character code then you have pretty few employees (there are only 17,576 potential combinations and you probably don't have to worry about most of them such as ZQR or LXX).  I would suggest that someone just manually enter the code when the record is created -- or use a more sustainable approach.  Such three character codes are hallmarks of the 1970s -- we have progressed far beyond that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff... might not be a mainstream need, agreed. Might not be very time consuming to write such a query on the other hand either. Just to produce a value by default.

Comment: @GordonLinoff... There are 200 or so employees

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . Do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employe;
CREATE TABLE employe (
id int primary key,
first_name varchar(30),
last_name varchar(30),
code1 char(3),
nb1 int NULL,
code2 char(3),
code char(3) NULL
);
insert into employe (id, first_name, last_name, code1, code2)
VALUES (1,'LUDOVIC','AUBERT','LAU','LUA'),(2,'LUDOVICO','AUBERT','LAU','LUA');

SELECT * FROM employe;
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, first_name, last_name, code1, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY code1 ORDER BY id ASC) as n1, code2
    FROM employe
)  
SELECT *, CASE WHEN n1=1 THEN code1 ELSE code2 END AS code FROM cte;
```

[image]